# In R, how do I spread a dummy variable value to everyone in a group (i.e., household) using something in the tidyverse?

Tags: r

I have data of individuals grouped into households. I'm trying to create a household-level dummy variable indicating a household with children. I've created a individual-level Child variable based on the observation's age. I'd like to "spread" this value, if it's a 1, to all members of the household.

The data looks like this:

```
HHID Child
1    0
1    1
1    0
2    0
2    1
3    0
3    0
3    0
```

I'd like the data frame like this:

```
HHID Child HH_child
1    0     1
1    1     1
1    0     1
2    0     1
2    1     1
3    0     0
3    0     0
3    0     0
```

I think it can be done using sqldf, but I'd like to do it in Tidyverse. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse/dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(HHID) %>% 
  mutate(HH_child = if_else(any(Child == 1),1,0))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
   HHID Child HH_child
  <int> <int>    <dbl>
1     1     0        1
2     1     1        1
3     1     0        1
4     2     0        1
5     2     1        1
6     3     0        0
7     3     0        0
8     3     0        0
```

Data:

```
structure(list(HHID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Child = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0b952498>, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(HHID) %>% 
  mutate(HH_child = max(Child))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also coerce to binary

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(HHID) %>%
       mutate(HH_child = +(1 %in% Child))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$HH_child <- with(df, ave(Child == 1, HHID, FUN = any))
```